# Odd triple click in OSX lion on a Wacom tablet

Tags: macos

I have been having an issue where my tablet will force three clicks instead of two when I double click anything.  I have tried troubleshooting it via wacoms forums and google searches and I cant find anyone else having this issue.

I use a Wacom intuos 5 medium.

I have multiple monitors too which I have read sometimes causes conflicts on tablets.

I thought it might be the tablet so I purchased a brand new one and the same thing keeps happening.

I would love to get back my normal double click - any ideas?

Comment: Did you change the doubleclick distance setting? Try to reset it to default and see if that helps.

Comment: Had the same problem with the Wacom Intuos Touch in Windows 10. The only answer suggested fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turn the "Tip Double Click Distance" completely OFF.